# Deploying Asp.NET Core Application Gives Http 500 Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a Asp.NET Core application(1.0 rc2 preview) and GoDaddy Windows Plesk hosting plan, I tried web deploy, ftp deploy but they gave me the same result which is "There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

I thougt maybe there is an error in my code, so I created new project(sample application) and tried to deploy but I got same result: "There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed."

GoDaddy Asp.Net version : 4.6.1
IIS Version: 8.5

What I have tried so far:

I added configuration to web.config

```
   <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
    <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true"/>
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
</system.web>
```

but this didn't help me. I still got error 500, not detailed error.

Comment: Did you check with GoDaddy to know if they support .NET core? ASP.NET core through IIS requires a little bit more work than regular ASP.NET. You need the handlers and change the app pool etc etc.

refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/iis) for more help!

Comment: @DOMZE Godaddy does not provide the IIS management UI, I can't change IIS settings.

Answer (score 0):

After googling, I found the following when it comes to ASP.NET core, godaddy and plesk:

Dated : 2016-11-04

> I checked with one of our developers and the integration of Core 1.0
>   is something we're in the process of considering. However, there's
>   currently no timeframe for when or if this will happen. It's
>   unfortunate, but I can understand that you may consider another
>   provider if this is a feature you need. We definitely appreciate the
>   feedback, regardless.

[Link](https://ca.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Web-Hosting/ASP-NET-Core-1-0-is-out-Will-GoDaddy-hosting-plans-support-this/m-p/14527/highlight/true#M534)

Full thread [here](https://ca.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Web-Hosting/ASP-NET-Core-1-0-is-out-Will-GoDaddy-hosting-plans-support-this/m-p/4890)

Comment: I saw this but I thought they support now because almost 8 months passed. Also asp 4.6.1 support core, doesnt it?

Comment: It doesn't work entirely like that.

ASP.NET runs on kestrel. By having the handlers installed, IIS just acts as a proxy, sending the traffic to the underlying webserver (kestrel). That's why the configuration is different.
Has plesk integrated it? Maybe. That is something I'm not familiar with. If plesk integrates it, is it something that GoDaddy wants to integrate and manage? that's also to be discussed with them. As the moderator said, you may consider another provider if this is a feature you need